# Nuxt JS event listener fires twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have Nuxt JS 2.9.x running in universal mode with a component loaded into every page. I'm using two event listeners: `blur` and `focus`, which should both run separately. The `blur` event listener should only run when the browser tab is switched, but appears to be running on page load... How could I change this? My component JS:

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('blur', this.blurTitle(false));
    document.addEventListener('focus', this.blurTitle(true));
  },
  methods: {

    blurTitle(location) {
      const currentPageTitle = document.title
      if (location) {
        document.title = currentPageTitle
      } else {
        document.title = 'Please come back...'
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I'm trying to display some different text when navigating away from the page, but when returning, display the original page title. The site will be compiled into the statically generated site.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `blurTitle` immediately. This:

```js
document.addEventListener('blur', this.blurTitle(false));
```

is equivalent to this:

```js
const fn = this.blurTitle(false)

document.addEventListener('blur', fn);
```

I suspect what you want is something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('blur', this.blurTitle.bind(this, false));
```

This creates a new function from `this.blurTitle` with the first argument bound to `false`.

Or if you prefer arrows functions:

```js
document.addEventListener('blur', () => this.blurTitle(false));
```

This creates a wrapper function that will call `blurTitle`, passing `false`.